# Mapbox doesn't shows map on Android O

Tags: android, mapbox, android-8.0-oreo

I am integrating the MapBox SDK in my android app. It works fine on all android Version except android O. It loads the screen with "mapbox" mark on the bottom of screen but never renders the map.The app gets stuck and freezes and then the map is never dis[image]played on android O version.
I am also using airmap in my app. Please let me know if something conflicts If i use both of them simultaneously.

**DashboardActivity,**

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
        getActivityComponent().inject(this);
        setUnBinder(ButterKnife.bind(this));
        mPresenter.onAttach(DashboardActivity.this);
        mapView = (AirMapMapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.addOnMapDataChangedListener(this);
        mapView.addOnMapLoadListener(this);
        configuration = new AirMapMapView.DynamicConfiguration(null, null, true);
        mapView.configure(configuration);
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);
        setAirmapView(mapView);
        mapView.setOnTouchListener(this);
        toggleCamera.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        dswStatus.setOnStatusChangeCallback(this);
        setUp();
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mapView.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mapView.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mapView != null) mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
```

**Logcat:**

```
07-12 12:13:08.241 2898-3381/? E/SecUISvc: Error initializing local socket: -1
07-12 12:13:09.243 2898-3381/? E/SecUISvc: Error initializing local socket: -1
07-12 12:13:09.483 548-621/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: Invalid profile no. 0, total profiles 0 only
07-12 12:13:09.485 1448-2121/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityStartTrigger: not whiteListedcom.mcx/com.mcx.ui.dashboard.DashboardActivity/1
07-12 12:13:09.485 1448-2121/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: not whiteListedcom.mcx/com.mcx.ui.dashboard.DashboardActivity/1
07-12 12:13:09.493 1448-2904/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: not whiteListedcom.mcx/com.mcx.ui.dashboard.DashboardActivity/1
07-12 12:13:09.885 448-448/? E/SELinux: avc:  denied  { find } for interface=vendor.qti.hardware.perf::IPerf pid=21765 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:hal_perf_hwservice:s0 tclass=hwservice_manager
07-12 12:13:09.886 448-448/? E/SELinux: avc:  denied  { find } for interface=vendor.qti.hardware.perf::IPerf pid=21765 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:hal_perf_hwservice:s0 tclass=hwservice_manager
07-12 12:13:09.887 21765-21765/com.mcx E/ANDR-PERF-JNI: IPerf::tryGetService failed!
07-12 12:13:10.245 2898-3381/? E/SecUISvc: Error initializing local socket: -1
07-12 12:13:11.246 2898-3381/? E/SecUISvc: Error initializing local socket: -1
07-12 12:13:12.248 2898-3381/? E/SecUISvc: Error initializing local socket: -1
07-12 12:13:13.250 2898-3381/? E/SecUISvc: Error initializing local socket: -1
07-12 12:13:14.251 2898-3381/? E/SecUISvc: Error initializing local socket: -1
```

Comment: Please post actual code that produces the problem, not a screenshot.

Comment: Did you find any solution for your problem?